# C# Windows Forms Display a Picture Box for a short time

Tags: c#, winforms

I couldn't find the answer to this question anywhere. Is there any command that displays a picture box for a specified amount of milliseconds? I know I could do thread.sleep or task.delay. But is there an alternative to these? Something that replaces:

```
picturebox1.visible = true; 
thread.sleep(1000); 
picturebox1.visible = false;
```

Thanks alot !

Comment: Use a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `Task.Delay` or even `Thread.Sleep`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Thread.Sleep`, `Task.Delay` or you can use a `Timer` which is described in other answers.

Probably you don't like to use `Task.Delay` or `Thread.Sleep` because you think it makes your program to go to a blocking and freezing state. You can use `Thread.Sleep` in a different thread to prevent freezing the form:

```
this.pictureBox1.Visible = true;
Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    }));
});
//Other codes which you put here, will not wait and will run immediately.
//Then after 5 seconds the picture box will be invisible again.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    picturebox1.visible = true;
    Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
    MyTimer.Interval = (1000);
    MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
    MyTimer.Start();
}

private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    picturebox1.visible = false;
    (sender as Timer).Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using GDI+. Instead of using `PictureBox`, simply add a handler for your form's `Paint` event. Inside it, draw your image using `e.Graphics.DrawImage()` method. Use a global bool variable that you should set to false after 1 second (or whatever your requirement is). In the `Paint` event, check this variable before drawing your image. Something like this:

```
bool DrawImage = true;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith((t) =>
  {
    DrawImage = false;
    Invalidate();
  });
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  if (DrawImage)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(YOUR_IMAGE_HERE, 0, 0);
}
```