# Make Label visible for 5 seconds in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, label

I am creating a WinForms application in visual studio 2017.

I have a Login form where, if the user enters a wrong username or password, a label that has the property visible = false, becomes visible for 5 seconds and the goes back for being not visible.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
label3.Visible = true;
Thread.Sleep(3000);
label3.Visible = false;
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, I couldn' find anyone with a very similar problem online, so I hope you could help me with this.

I have seen other soloutions using this:

```
var t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 3000; // it will Tick in 3 seconds
t.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    label3.Hide();
    t.Stop();
};
t.Start();
```

but I get an error saying "a local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local parameter".

Comment: the problem you hit was that you told the UI thread to sleep, as a result it never painted the label.  then once it was about to paint it it was told to hide it again.

Comment: `label1.Visible = true; await Task.Delay(3000); label1.Visible = false;`

Comment: You may also find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36249743/3110834) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename `e` to some other variable as the error says you are already having a local variable named `e` in the scope.

```
var t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 3000; // it will Tick in 3 seconds
t.Tick += (s, event) =>
{
    label3.Hide();
    t.Stop();
};
t.Start();
```

Answer (score 6):

if you're using .NET Framework 4.5 or above, you can also have done it with this code:

```
label3.Visible = true;
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=> { label3.Visible = false; }));
});
```